# Do best-practices say to restrict the usage of /var to sudoers?

Tags: linux, package-management

I wrote a package, and would like to use `/var` to persist some data.  The data I'm storing would perhaps even be thought of as an addition for `/var/db`.

The pattern I observe is that files in `/var/db`, and the surrounds, are owned by `root`.  The primary (intended) use of the package filters cron jobs - meaning you would need permissions to edit the crontab.

1. Should I presume a sudo install of the package?
2. Should I have the package gracefully degrade to a `/usr` subdir, and if so then which one?
3. If I 'opinionate' that any non-sudo install requires a `configrc` (with paths), where should the package look (presuming a shared-host environment) for that config file?

Incidentally, this package is a ruby gem, and [you can find it here](http://github.com/newalexandria/morpheus).

Comment: Personally think this question is more suitable for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com) forum.

Comment: @skrco Please don't direct users to other sites when their question is absolutely fine to stay here. We have almost 15.000 Linux and Unix questions on Super User – we don't need to push questions away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard and http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) (which, as Linux sysadmin, I'd highly recommend) you should use `/var/lib/<your application name>` to store persistent data:

> `/var/lib` holds state information pertaining to an application or
>   the system. **State information is data that programs modify while they
>   run**, and that pertains to one specific host. Users must never need to
>   modify files in /var/lib to configure a package's operation.
>
> **An application (or a group of inter-related applications) must use a
>   subdirectory of /var/lib for its data**. There is one required
>   subdirectory, /var/lib/misc, which is intended for state files that
>   don't need a subdirectory; the other subdirectories should only be
>   present if the application in question is included in the
>   distribution.

This means the package should be indeed installed with `sudo`. On the other hand, notice that any subdirectory in `/usr` (`/user/local` would be a second possibility) would require `sudo` too, since they belong to `root`. So if you want to fall back to a non-sudo installation, I'd say `~/bin` is a good choice.

The package itself only needs to run as `root` if it's used to edit other users' crontabs.

As of `configrc`, if you mean this: https://github.com/nerab/config-rc I can't give you any piece of advice because I don't know it.